# Checking PH assumption for a time dependent (T_COV) variable in a Cox PH-regression: with or without the original covariate in the regression?

Tags: survival, spss, cox-model, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

I am performing a cox proportional hazard regression on survival, in a sample in which almost everyone dies in the follow up period. I have little knowledge on statistics in general but i am reading as much as I can and try to move carefully. I want to be sure to thoroughly check the PH assumption. I can get some help from a statistician, but it takes 2 weeks til i can get an appointment (I will!)

I found 2 methods for checking the PH assumption that i can easily perform in SPSS: visually I can inspect stratified log minus log plots (and scatterplots of residuals for continuous variables). My question is about the statistical method: checking if the product of time and covariate becomes significant in the cox regression (if yes, not fulfilling PH assumption). 
I havenoticed that it is quite common to first make an univariable cox regression for each covariate. I have been reading on the subject but see that different methods are used when it comes to check individual Time dependent covariates.

Some people check the product of time*variable (T_COV) univariable in the cox-regression, others put both the T_COV and the original variable in the cox regression (example for age: T*Age and age would both be taken into the cox-regression). In the second method, one does noet acquire univariable cox regression for the T_COV.

Why is it important to me? There is one T_COV variable for the location of the tumor that is not significant in univariable cox- regression, but becomes significant in the regression with only the T_COV and the original variable that it is a product of (T*tumorlocation).

I hope you want to give me your thoughts on the topic. I am extra happy with reading recommendations/reliable sources!
If you have other remarks, questions, or if my methods are all wrong: please comment! Is it helpful if i write down the specific HR's etc?

Comment: How can tumor location be a time-dependent covariate. Does the location of the tumor change over time?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look at the analysis involving both the predictor itself and the interaction with time.

Another way to look at the proportional hazards issue is to save partial residuals from an analysis with the predictor of interest in it and to examine a plot of them against time. If the proportional hazards assumption is met, this plot should not show any pattern.